# Bathroom faucet cold water only works if hot turned on first

Tags: bathroom, faucet

When the cold water handle of my bathroom faucet is turned on by itself no water comes out.  This is a two handled one spout faucet.  If I turn on the hot water first, then I can turn on the cold and it will continue to flow after the hot is turned off and can be turned off with the hot water handle.

Comment: Even without knowing the cause I think to repair it you'll need to take it apart.  And therefore, it would make sense to take it apart now rather than speculate on the cause.  A picture of the faucet would help us to speculate.  A picture of the *disassembled* faucet would be even more helpful.  You can press Edit (above) and copy/paste pictures into your Question.

Comment: Is this a new installation or first problem with an old faucet?  Make and model if known will help.

Comment: What do you mean by "after the hot is turned off" it "can be turned off with the hot water handle"?  Explain?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.